# The Force Dark side posses you?

Tags: star-wars

When you tun to the dark side is like you have been possesed by a demon? you lost your sanity? That bring me to the mind seeing how ...

> Anakin kills all the young padawans

...something that nobody (not insane) would do for most angry you are.

Comment: This is directly addressed by the dupe question.

Comment: JeanPaul is incorrect, unfortunately.  Killing children for some weak or strong reason is very common in history and thus there is every reason to think that most of the evil child killers were clinically sane.